# How to have a method in superclass that validates a field in the subclass

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract

I have an abstract superclass Employee and 2 subclasses Manager and Worker. I want to make a method in Employee that can add benefits - Managers can have benefits, Workers not.

I tried to do the following:

```
Employee has -> protected boolean rightsForBenefits;
    Manager has -> final protected boolean rightsForBenefits = true;
    Worker has -> final protected boolean rightsForBenefits = false;
```

Now in Employee I have this method

```
private void checkBenefitStatus() {
        if(!rightsForBenefits) {
            throw new RuntimeException("You are not allegeable to benefits");
        }
    }

    public void addBenefit(String benefit) {
        if(rightsForBenefits) {
    ...
    }
```

But when I try to use this method, it always validates Employee.rightsForBenefit. How to point it to verify the rightsForBenefits of the subclasses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields in java are not subject to polymorphism. The `rightsForBenefits` field in your `Employee` class will always refer to the field in the `Employee` class itself, not any subclass. you should use a method. not a field.

```
public abstract class Employee {
    protected abstract boolean getRightsForBenefits();

    private void checkBenefitStatus() {
        if(!getRightsForBenefits()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("You are not allegeable to benefits");
        }
    }

    public void addBenefit(String benefit) {
        checkBenefitStatus();
        // add benefits logic
    }
}

public class Manager extends Employee {
    @Override
    protected boolean getRightsForBenefits() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Worker extends Employee {
    @Override
    protected boolean getRightsForBenefits() {
        return false;
    }
}
```